# Pointer to one row in dynamically allocated 2D array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, dynamic

I have a dynamically allocated 2D array Volatility[r][c] with r rows and c columns in C++. Is it somehow possible to create a pointer ptrColumn to a certain column c1, such that I can access the element (r1,c1) with ptrColumn[r1]?
So far, I tried to create dynamic pointers. But I didn't manage to do it.
Thank you!

Comment: "dynamically allocated 2D array" is not a well-defined term in C++. There are at least 2 different ways to dynamically allocate a 2D array. You need to provide more information about the physical structure of your array in memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not possible. One alternative you have is to create another 2D array with a traspose of the original array but is just useless because you'd have to update this array every time original array changes. Perhaps there is other ways to do it but an array of columns just don't.

Comment: Bote the title of the question. The OP does not express correctly what he/she wants.

Answer (score 1):

You need a `stride` iterator. The `++` operator for a normal pointer returns a new pointer with an offset `1`; for a `stride` iterator, the `++` operator will return a new `stride` iterator with a physical offset `c`; And so for operator `[]`, `+` and `--`; Here is a simple example:

```
template< typename Iterator_Type >
struct stride_iterator
{
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator_Type>::value_type                value_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator_Type>::reference                 reference;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator_Type>::difference_type           difference_type;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator_Type>::pointer                   pointer;
    typedef typename std::iterator_traits<Iterator_Type>::iterator_category             iterator_category;

    Iterator_Type iterator_;
    difference_type step_;

    stride_iterator( Iterator_Type it, difference_type dt ) : iterator_(it), step_(dt) {}

    reference operator []( difference_type dt )
    { return iterator_[dt*step_]; }

    //other ctors, dtor and operators
};
```

This case, suppose the pointer holding the 2D array is `double** dat`, and the dimension for the array is `r` by `c`, you can create a `column iterator` at column index `c1` with

```
auto col_itor = stride_iterator<double*>{ dat + c1, c };
```

and access the element at `dat[r1][c1]` with operator []

```
auto& elem = col_itor[r1];
```

Answer (score 0):

Usually the first dimention is for row index, and the second for column.
First you should allocate memory for array of pointers (e.g. `int *`) and save addres as pointer to pointers:

```
int** Volatility = new int * [r];
```

Then arrange loop to allocate memory for each row. E.g.:

```
for(int i = 0; i < r; i++)
      Volatility[i] = new int [c];
```

But it is your desition how to work with indexes.

If you want to work with columns on first index, just change the logic:

```cpp
    int r = 5, c = 10;
    int** Volatility = new int * [c];
    // allocate memory for each column
    for(int i = 0; i < c; i++)
    {
        Volatility[i] = new int [r];
    }
```

As you see `Volatility[col][row]` is a single element, and `Volatility[col]` is a pointer to columt. But now you cannot work with pointer to row.

Comment: I think the OP wants just the opposite, that is, create pointers to the columns, not the rows. Well...after reading the title of the question, perhaps, you are right

Comment: @AntonioGarrido exactly

Comment: new does not return NULL is case of error. It thows bad_alloc. Your code seems to be more C than C++

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way, for me, is to reserve the block of memory:

```
double* array2d= new double[r*c];
```

then, you can calculate the pointers as array2d+index*r (remember, the block of memory stores the array column by column, from the first to the last column).

IF you want to calculate the pointers to rows, use array2d+index*r (in this case, the memory stores the array row after row.

If you want the pointers in some place to use double operator [][], you could use:

```
double **array= new double*[r];
for (int i=1; i<r; ++i)
   array[i]= array[i-1]+c;
```

For this code, you could use array[i][j] in your code.